# Cannot match string from the end

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the last nested list from the following string

```
data = '|[[1385827200000,5955],[1388505600000,5955],[1391184000000,5955],[1393603200000,5955],[1438358400000,53192],[1441036800000,53946],[1443628800000,65779]]&abc   &|[[1541001600000,60891],[1543593600000,60910],[1546272000000,60964],[1548950400000,61005],[1551369600000,60864],[1554048000000,61309],[1556640000000,61092],[1559318400000,62556],[1561910400000,62379],[1564588800000,64356],[1567267200000,65979],[1569859200000,65979]]&def   &|'

text = re.findall('(\[\[.*\]\])$', data)
```

But it gives `None`.

What is the correct expression?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: The `data` string does not end with `]]` so there is no way that the regex `\]\]$` could match. Please [edit] to clarify what you hope to match and how you think your regex accomplishes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input doesn't end with `]]` hence placing an anchor `$` won't work in your regex.

You may use this regex to get last pair of `[[...]]` from input:

```
>>> text = re.findall(r'.*(\[\[.*?\]\])', data)[0]
>>> print (text)
'[[1541001600000,60891],[1543593600000,60910],[1546272000000,60964],[1548950400000,61005],[1551369600000,60864],[1554048000000,61309],[1556640000000,61092],[1559318400000,62556],[1561910400000,62379],[1564588800000,64356],[1567267200000,65979],[1569859200000,65979]]'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1rK0oZ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*`: Greedy match at start to match longest possible string
- `(\[\[.*?\]\])`: Match and capture text between `[[...]]`.

Comment: I found that `re.findall(r'.*(\[\[.*?\]\])', data)[0]` is the same as `re.findall(r'.*(\[\[.*\]\])', data)[0]`. What is the difference in operation?

Comment: Usually, it is safer to use `.*?` (non-greedy) to avoid matching longest string between `[[` and `]]` as intent is ti capture last pair of `[[...]]` but in this case `re.findall(r'.*(\[\[.*\]\])', data)[0]` would work fine as well since we have `.*` at start.

Answer (score 1):

Your text doesn't end with ']}' as being searched by you.
It actually ends with '&def   &|'
So use

```
text = re.findall('(\[\[.*?\]\])&def   &|$', data)
```

Comment: `.*` is wrong, it will fetch the longest possible string. `.*?` might work if the input is always expected to be well-formed.

Comment: This is returning 2 elements in output.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `regex`:

```
nested_list = eval(data.split('&|')[-2].split('&')[0])
```

Or,

```
nested_list = eval(data.split('&')[-3].strip('|'))
```

But this is totally case-specific.